# Angular: Drag and Drop mat preview is not showing

Tags: angular, angular-material

Sorry for stupid question.

The preview's not showing when I created child components and put **directive** into them like this:

```
            <div *ngFor="let item of items"
                 cdkDropList
                 [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="id">
              <app-child1 [params]="params" *cdkDragPreview/>
              <app-child2 [params]="params" *cdkDragPreview/>
            </div>
```

It works properly without child component

What is going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cdkDragPreview  has to be within a parent element with the cdkDrag directive and you can only have one cdkDragPreview (instead of the two that you have). See the example:

```
 <div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>
    {{movie.title}}
    <img *cdkDragPreview [src]="movie.poster" [alt]="movie.title">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Official Angular Example of cdkDragPreview](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lyqvmqvyglj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-custom-preview-example.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!
I just added cdkDrag and it's still not showing

Comment: I know it's a bit tricky so I made an example for you based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93pedc?file=src/app/cdk-drag-drop-custom-preview-example.html